# innerHtml of a variable does update but returns back

Tags: javascript, html

Even though the function deposit() updates the innerHTML it, unfortunately, returns back the constant variable of **bal**.

```js
var bal = 100;

var currentBalance = document.getElementById("REPLACED")
currentBalance.innerHTML = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos"


function deposit() {
  var moneygiven = parseInt(document.getElementById("balance").value);
  bal += moneygiven
  if (moneygiven > 0) {
    bal += moneygiven
    var output = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos";
    // Display result
    currentBalance.innerHTML = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos"
  } else {
    alert("Error")
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Code</p>
  <h1 id="REPLACED"></h1>
  <form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="00000" id="balance" name="balanceNumber" />
    <button onclick="deposit()" value="" id="btnDeposit">Deposit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It is because the page is refreshing when you click the button. Add `event.preventDefault()` to your `deposit()` function.

Comment: Why are you running  `bal += moneygiven` twice?

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default `type` for `button` is `submit`.

You don't want your `button` to submit your form when clicked, so change it to `type="button"`.

```js
var bal = 100;

var currentBalance = document.getElementById("REPLACED")
currentBalance.innerHTML = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos"


function deposit() {
  var moneygiven = parseInt(document.getElementById("balance").value);
  // bal += moneygiven // not sure if you really want this line of code twice in case of moneygiven > 0
  if (moneygiven > 0) {
    bal += moneygiven
    var output = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos";
    // Display result
    currentBalance.textContent = "Current balance: " + bal + " Pesos"
  } else {
    alert("Error")
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Code</p>
  <h1 id="REPLACED"></h1>
  <form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="00000" id="balance" name="balanceNumber" />
    <button onclick="deposit()" value="" id="btnDeposit" type="button">Deposit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, there is no need to work with the unsafe  `innerHTML` property here; use `textContent` whenever you don't need to inject HTML.